# Condition for the union of two affine subspaces to be an affine subspace

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, affine-geometry

I have already read this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3559923) to the question [Union of two affine subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557061/union-of-two-affine-subspaces), but I have tried to write down a different proof of the following proposition.

> Let $\mathcal{E}$ be an affine space over a $K$-vector space $E$, where $\mathrm{char}\ K \neq 2$. Let's suppose $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ are affine subspaces of $\mathcal{E}$, whose directions are the vector subspaces $F_1$ and $F_2$ of $E$, respectively. The union $\mathcal{F_1 \cup F_2}$ is an affine subspace of $\mathcal{E}$ if and only if $\mathcal{F}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{F}_2$ or $\mathcal{F}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{F}_1$.

The ''if'' part is straightforward: if $\mathcal{F}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{F}_2$, then $\mathcal{F}_1 \cup \mathcal{F}_2 = \mathcal{F}_2$, which is an affine subspace by hypothesis; if $\mathcal{F}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{F}_1$, then $\mathcal{F}_1 \cup \mathcal{F}_2 = \mathcal{F}_1$, which is an affine subspace by hypothesis.

In order to prove the ''only if'' part, let's suppose $\mathcal{F}_1 \cup \mathcal{F}_2$ is an affine subspace, whose direction is the vector subspace $F$ of $E$.
Assume the thesis is false. Then we can pick $A \in \mathcal{F}_1 \setminus \mathcal{F}_2$ and $B \in \mathcal{F}_2 \setminus \mathcal{F}_1$.

Since $\mathcal{F}_1 \cup \mathcal{F}_2$ is an affine subspace, the vector $\vec{AB}$ is an element of $F$ and there exists $P \in \mathcal{F}_1 \cup \mathcal{F}_2$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\vec{AP} = \frac{1}{2} \vec{AB}.
\end{equation*}

Such a point $P$ must belong to $\mathcal{F}_1$ or to $\mathcal{F}_2$.

If $P \in \mathcal{F}_1$, then $\vec{AP} \in F_1$, and we also have $\vec{AB} \in F_1$ (because $\vec{AB} = 2 \vec{AP}$), which leads to the contradiction $B \in \mathcal{F}_1$.

If $P \in \mathcal{F}_2$, then $\vec{BP} \in F_2$, and we also have $\vec{BA} \in F_2$ (because $\vec{BA} = 2 \vec{BP}$), which leads to the contradiction $A \in \mathcal{F}_1$, and the proof is complete.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Why is it that $\vec{AB}$ is in $\mathcal{F}_1 \cup \mathcal{F}_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct.
You should however introduce $F$ as the vector subspace of directions of your putative affine subspace $\mathcal{F}_1\cup\mathcal{F}_2$ first. You also could introduce $\mathcal{F}:=\mathcal{F}_1\cup\mathcal{F}_2$ to make notation a bit lighter.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure where I should introduce $F$: should it be introduced before my sentence ''Let's suppose $\mathcal{F}_1 \cup \mathcal{F}_2$ is an affine subspace, whose direction is the vector subspace $F$ of $E$''?

Comment: Definitely. Introduce all notation before you use it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I didn't use $F$ before that sentence. Is it correct if I change that sentence in "Let's suppose $\mathcal{F}_1 \cup \mathcal{F}_2$ is an affine subspace and call $F$ its vector subspace of directions"?

Comment: Phrasing it like this improves understandability. It's fine now.